# Stylesheet not recognizing custom font

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-awesome

I am having problems getting my Icomoon custom fonts to load within my website.

---

**Screenshot of Inspected Icon**

[image: Here is a screenshot showing my inspection of an icon element]

I'm assuming that the greyed out "returnflight" reference indicates that my font files are not sourced correctly. I do not understand why that would be the case considering my /css/ and my /fonts/ folders sit at the same level.

---

**My File Structure**

[image: File structure]

---

**My Styles Within global.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "returnflight";
    src: url("../fonts/returnflight.woff?5h0ljc") format('woff');
}

.fa {
    font-family: 'returnflight' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-auto-intelligence-01:before {
    content: "\e900";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

I have removed all src's within @font-face except for .woff as suggested, but still experiencing the issue.

[image]

---

**Net Tab Error**

Upon enabling the Net tab within firebug I am seeing the following error which could be unrelated but I'm not sure. I was just brought in on this project and it is a robust piece of software. This seems to be related to bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: please stop using all those font formats, it's no longer 2010. Just use WOFF, [everything supports it](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF) (in modern browsers SVG and EOT fonts aren't even recognized formats anymore)

Comment: Ok, sure. Do you have any suggestions on why the font wouldn't be rendering though?

Comment: directly related to my first comment. Remove all the redundant formats so that we're not trying to rediscover that browser X doesn't support format Y. If you still have this problem after using just WOFF, so every browser's behaviour is deterministic, we can start looking at what's really going wrong.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the src but am still experiencing the issue. Please see the EDIT at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @jetlej There is one error within console that says "Network error: A network error occurred". This software uses iframes to display a lot of information regarding statistics and Im assuming this error has something to do with one of the other widgets further down the page failing.

Comment: maybe, but let's not assume, let's be sure: what does the network tab show? Also your post is still showing a million font formats being used...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's actually not showing the error anymore. It looks like the failing widget is back up. I have updated my CSS excerpt above to only show the woff format.

Comment: so, no 404s in the network tab for your font, and no OTS errors if you explicitly turn on all CSS errors and warnings for the console?

Comment: Actually yes, just opened up the network tab just now and it looks like I have a 403 error. I will paste it within my original question.

Comment: I talked to another guy that works at this company and he said it turns out it was a path issue that had to do with the application structure. I can post more whenever I get more details. Thank you everyone for your time in helping me look into this.

Comment: That error message is related to the icon fonts that are bundled with bootstrap. Looking at your fonts folder in the attached picture, they don't look like they are there? Regardless it is not the issue stopping your font from working. Are there any errors in relation to your 'returnflight' font? Or are you able to confirm whether it has loaded or not? I've had issues in the past where the mime type for fonts file types needed to be configured in IIS or added in the '.htaccess' file to allow those fonts to be loaded by the browser,

Answer (score 0):

That 403 error will do it. Looks like you are either loading fonts from a different server (sometimes even www -> no www will do it, depending on server configs), the font files/folder don't have the right permissions, or you have something in .htaccess that is blocking access to certain file types.